# PHP/Apache2 - list of zip files from directory listing, not downloadable

Tags: php, apache2, file-handling

Running on a subdomain with Apache2 and PHP7. I use the current code to create a list of zip files from the current directory.

```
  1 <?php
  2     $fileList = glob('*.zip');
  3     
  4     echo '<ul>';
  5     
  6     foreach($fileList as $filename){
  7      echo '<li><a href="', $filename, '">', $filename, '</a></li>';
  8     }
  9     
 10     echo '</ul>';
 11     
 12 ?>
```

When I visit the page, it displays the content as expected however when I click on a link to a zip file I receive a 404 Not Found page. The link looks like it should point to the file, right-clicking and saving the target as, downloads an html file of the 404 page.

I am unsure as to what could be causing this issue and any help/guidance on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do the addresses in the href field look like? Have you examined that? The file list in the example consists of absolute file system paths, not http absolute URLs or relative URI paths as you would need.

Comment: The href field looks normal using safari web inspector, It says that its pointing to the files in question.
I have changed the href field to include https:// sub.domain.co.uk/folder/$filename" but with no difference.

Comment: Are these URL's being sent to e.g php-fpm and it's emitting the 404?